# Graph unable to update permissions for an external user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Recently something is changed the way Graph is handling permissions on drive items for external(outside tenant users).

Previously when we give access Write access to an external a unique link was created per user that we can do a patch call to update the roles if we want.

Now only two links are created one which is common for all externals having write role and one for read role.

[image]
I could not find a way if I want to update the role of an external from write to read or vice versa without removing all external users with write and adding them again.

Is there a work around to update permissions for external. The documentation is also pretty old its not updated since 2017.

Note: This is the [Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) we are using/recommended to update permissions.